# SQL WHERE command with multiple operators

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a database with a column labeled "pr_label" and "pr_quantity".  When we query our information  the items labeled as "C1" and "C2" display.  Below is the code we used in our SQL command

```
'pr_label' IN ('C1', 'C2')
```

but now we want to add an extra rule where we want to display all "C1" items and only "C2" items that have a value greater than zero in "pr_quantity".  So if we applied these rules the below table will only display info on 900, 901, 902 and 903.  904 and 905 would not display because 'pr_quantity' == 0.

```
 =====================================
 pr_id     | pr_label  | pr_quantity |
 =====================================
 900       | C1        | 4           |
 901       | C1        | 4           |
 902       | C1        | 4           |
 903       | C2        | 4           |
 904       | C2        | 0           |
 905       | C2        | 0           |
 =====================================
```

I am trying the code below which works but it applies to both "C1" and "C2".

```
`pr_quantity ` > 0
```

Comment: why dont you try like this, 'pr_label = 'C1' or ('pr_label = 'C2' and pr_quantity > 0').

Comment: You have a space in your last expression.  Without the space, it should work.

Comment: The hint is inside your question itself - "I am trying the code below which works but it applies to both "C1" and "C2"." Why not try to apply it just one ? This is simple if you know the basics of sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to simply say:

```
WHERE (pr_label = 'C1')
    OR (pr_label = 'C2' AND pr_quantity > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer this

> we want to display all "C1" items and only "C2" items that have a
>   value greater than zero in "pr_quantity"

the following query would be handy (I'm going to call this as product table)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE 
pr_label = 'C1' OR (pr_label = 'C2' AND pr_quantity > 0)
```